# Route simulation not working in andriod emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, location-services

I am building a flutter app which has location tracking capabilities. As part of the test, I want to simulate the device moving along a route. I have been doing this well for sometime and all of a sudden it stopped working. When I try to access the saved routes it loads indefinitely. Please see screen below.

I created another device using Device manager on android studio, I also unstalled android studio and installed again. In addition, I also wiped the data from the devices using android studio. I was expecting that one of these would resolve the problem but nothing worked